# com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView in API Level < 21

Tags: java, android, api, admob, adview

Good Night!

I'm trying put a AdMob im my Project, but it just work in API Level 21 or 22, when I change the preview for API less then 21, i have a Null Pointer Exception, and if I try compile and install in a Device with Android 2 3 or Android 4 0, the Ad does't appear, and debuging, throws a Null Pointer Exception.

I'm using the Android Studio 1 2 2 with the SDK packages updateds.

Bellow the error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
-com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

And the Complete Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:157)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.zza.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzk.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzk.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:369)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:326)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And the Build Gradle app File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.cinova.procuradominio"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
   }
```

And the Manifest Application Tag

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityPrincipal"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/icone"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultadoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/icone"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_resultado"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityConfiguracoes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_configuracoes" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the Activity AdView Tag:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I try several things, but nothing work

Somebody have a idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Exception you are seeing is from your IntelliJ IDE (ie Android Studio) in a preview render. This is never likely to be able to display an ad.

Test it on a real device or on an emulator.

Comment: William, I tested in a Real Device and in Emulator, but didin't work. Debugging has a difference, in Android 5, the AdView instance was recognized with the full google package, but in android < 5 just how AdView and the memory address.

Comment: Ask another question with the new error you are getting.